# Interrupt is sporatic, potentially after 220Hz or so

Tags: interrupt, pulsein

Background although likely not needed: I am recieving a frequency on the destination side of a opto isolater.  A fan trips a hall effect sensor, and grounds a circuit which lights the opto.  On the recieving end I have a fully isolated arduino circuit that accurately reads this 550Hz (peak) signal.  However, my Uno stopped reading this value correctly.  So I debounced the circuit which did not fix the issue.  I now brought in a new (and isolated) Uno that has nothing else going on but reading this signal and its Interrupt is also sporatic after several seconds.

I believe it is operating OK until the signal gets to about 420Hz (which is nothing..).  PulseIn also returns many "0" durations with the "900ns" good durations.  So it seems the high/low trigger is flipping too often, which was not fixed with debounce. I can see using the oscilloscope that the signal is good at 550Hz

```
21:34:12.750 -> Htz: 0
21:34:14.575 -> L: 44
21:34:14.575 -> Htz: 88
21:34:15.265 -> L: 70
21:34:15.265 -> Htz: 140
21:34:15.479 -> L: 89
21:34:15.479 -> Htz: 178
21:34:15.913 -> L: 109
21:34:15.913 -> Htz: 218
21:34:16.452 -> L: 117
21:34:16.577 -> Htz: 234
21:34:16.986 -> L: 134
21:34:16.986 -> Htz: 268
21:34:17.511 -> L: 186
21:34:17.511 -> Htz: 372
21:34:18.036 -> L: 213
21:34:18.036 -> Htz: 426
21:34:18.567 -> L: 702
21:34:18.567 -> Htz: 1404
21:34:19.195 -> L: 1913
21:34:19.196 -> Htz: 3826
21:34:19.838 -> L: 3508
21:34:19.838 -> Htz: 7016
```

code

```
unsigned long timestamp;
int lsensorpin = 2;
int PWMpin = 3;
String printout;
unsigned int reading;
unsigned long L;
unsigned int lRPM;
unsigned int Htz;

void setup() {
  pinMode(lsensorpin, INPUT);//_PULLUP); //2
  pinMode(PWMpin, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(PWMpin, 100);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("FInish Setup");
}

void loop() {

  //printout=" High:";
  //reading= pulseIn(lsensorpin, HIGH);
  //printout=printout + reading + " Low:";
  //reading= pulseIn(lsensorpin, LOW);
  //printout= printout + reading;
  //Serial.println(printout + reading);
  
  L=0;
  attachl();
  delay(500);
  detachl();
  Htz=L*2;
  lRPM= L*60;
  Serial.print("L: ");
  Serial.println(L);
  //Serial.print("Htz: ");
  //Serial.println(Htz);
  
  //Serial.print("RPM: ");
  //Serial.println(lRPM);
}

void tickL() {
L=L+1;
}

void attachl(){
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(lsensorpin), tickL, RISING);
}

void detachl(){
    detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(lsensorpin));
}
```

[image: Debounced Signal]

Comment: Did you consider that `delay()` is influenced by the interrupts? Each interrupt service takes some run time, and the delay is prolonged by that run time. The function realizes the delay through a certain number of instruction cycles. You might want to use a timer to realize the measurement interval.

Comment: Why are you attaching and detaching the interrupt in your main loop? Try using a faster baud rate, eg. 115200 baud. (9600 is really slow).

Answer (score 1):

From my [post about interrupts](http://gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11488&reply=10#reply10):

---

I have seen example code suggesting you count things for a second by turning interrupts off for a second and then on again. I don't recommend this, because for one thing, you can't do serial prints if interrupts are off.

### Example (not recommended):

```
volatile unsigned long events;
const unsigned long INTERVAL = 1000;  // 1 second

void eventISR ()     
  { 
  events++;  
  }   // end of eventISR

void setup () 
  { 
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  attachInterrupt (digitalPinToInterrupt (2), eventISR, FALLING); 
  }   // end of setup

void loop ()    
  {
  events = 0;       // reset counter
  interrupts ();    // allow interrupts    
  delay (INTERVAL); // wait desired time
  noInterrupts();   // stop interrupts

  Serial.print ("I counted ");
  Serial.println (events);
  }  // end of loop
```

That may work for simple situations, but turning interrupts off means that the Serial prints won't work until they are turned on again (which they may not be in a more complex sketch).

It is better to use the millis() result and just detect when the time limit is up.

### Improved sketch:

```
volatile bool counting;
volatile unsigned long events;

unsigned long startTime;
const unsigned long INTERVAL = 1000;  // 1 second

void eventISR ()
  {
  if (counting)
    events++;    
  }  // end of eventISR
  
void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
  attachInterrupt (digitalPinToInterrupt (2), eventISR, FALLING);
  }  // end of setup

void showResults ()
  {
  Serial.print ("I counted ");
  Serial.println (events);
  }  // end of showResults
  
void loop ()
  {
  if (counting)
    {
    // is time up?
    if (millis () - startTime < INTERVAL)
      return;  
    counting = false;
    showResults ();
    }  // end of if
    
  noInterrupts ();
  events = 0;
  startTime = millis ();
  EIFR = bit (INTF0);  // clear flag for interrupt 0
  counting = true;
  interrupts ();
  }  // end of loop
```

In loop() here we wait for the interval (1 second in this case) to be up, otherwise we return, effectively doing nothing. You could of course do other things instead of just returning.

If the time is up we display the count.

If counting is not currently active (and presuming we want it to be active) we remember the start time, reset the counter to zero, and let it start counting up.

That code seemed to work OK up to 100 kHz, although the counts were getting a bit inaccurate. You can do more precise timings by using the hardware counters / timers. Details here:

http://www.gammon.com.au/timers

---

Also you should declare the variable **L** to be volatile.

Comment: Interresting formatting, looks somehow like python style.. I can't see blocks properly either :D (subjective feeling)

Comment: @KIIV  Why? The entire block is indented. I find that is the easiest to read. I think it is called [Whitesmiths style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Whitesmiths_style). "It was also popular in the early days of Windows, ..." - I've been around for a while, so I probably picked up that style years ago.

Comment: It's just that I'm not used to this style. I'm somehow used to search end bracket with smaller indentation than code. You know, almost 2 decades of using one or two similar styles